# unable to use RODM to connect to Oracle database from R

Tags: oracle, r

I am trying to connect to an Oracle database from R.

I used `RODM_open_dbms_connection(dsn, uid = "", pwd = "")`, but it doesn't work. I am not sure what kind of the error it is.

Here is the error screen from R.

```
> library(RODM) Loading required package: RODBC DB<-
> RODM_open_dbms_connection(dsn="****",uid="****", pwd="****") Error in
> typesR2DBMS[[driver]] <<- value[c("double", "integer", "character",  :
> cannot change value of locked binding for 'typesR2DBMS'
```

Comment: After formatting that as a code block, it looks incomplete and a bit mangled. In particular the "DB<-"  at the end of the first line looks out of place. I'm wondering if your line separators are the problem

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [ROracle](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ROracle/index.html)?  After you get the instant client installed on your machine, connecting and fetching records from R looks like this:

```
library(ROracle)
con <- dbConnect(dbDriver("Oracle"), username="username", password="password", dbname = "dbname")
res <- dbSendQuery(con, "select * from schema.table")
dt <- data.table(fetch(res, n=-1))
```

Answer (score 0):

I explored the RODM_open_dbms_connection. I commented out the part ***setSqlTYpeInfo()***. After that I didn't receive that error.
Install RODM package from source then only you can edit the package.